# Looking up squares in matrices

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to go through a matrix made of zeroes and ones, which e.g. looks like this:

```
3 5
1 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
```

The first two digits are the number of rows and columns. Zeroes are whitespace, ones are actual "lines". I know that to go through a matrix, I need to use two nested loops like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        /* code */
```

I need to be able to save the top left coordinates and the bottom right coordinates of a square in a matrix.

I have the matrix saved in a one-dimensional field as well as the number of rows and cols. This particular matrix would look like this if printed to the screen:

```
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

I can't seem to find the right algorithm to recognize a square in any matrix of this kind. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: This isn't clear.  What result are you looking for in your example case?

Comment: "I need to be able to save the top left coordinates and the bottom right coordinates of a square in a matrix" - huh?

Comment: looks like you need four variables. was that your question?

Comment: yes, I know that part, the "square recognition" part is what bugs me

Comment: you haven't even mentioned this part...

Comment: If your square is in a 1D array and starts with 3 and 5. Count 2 elements for the first two digits. After that, the top left would be the first element in your 1D array, the bottom right would be the last element of your 1D array.

Comment: I suggest you write some code to print your array before you start trying to be clever. Once you can do that and understand it, you should see easily how to pick or skip this or that element or row from it. If your data is in a 2D array, get rows and cols from your first row. Then with your 2 loops start i from 1 so as to skip the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple algorithm:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows-2; i++) // scan all but last 2 rows since we scan down once we find the top of a square
    // Reset the count after each row
    int count = 0;
    int lastCell = -1;
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) { // Scan all columns
       // look for 3 cells in a row the same
       if (cells[i][j] == lastCell) {
          count++;
       } else {
          lastCell = cells[i][j];
          count=1;
       }
       if (count >= 3) {
          // Potential match found since we have a row of three the same
          // now check for the sides and bottom
          if (cells[i-2][j+1] == lastCell && cells[i-2][j+2] == lastCell && // left side
              cells[i][j+1] == lastCell && cells[i][j+2] == lastCell && // right side
              cells[i-1][j+2] == lastCell  // bottom
              ) {
                // Square detected - do whatever you like here :)
                // i, j is the top right corner of the detected square
           }
       }
    }
```

If you need the square to be hollow then check for the center square != lastCell.

If you only need squares of a certain value then only check for that value.